# Codeigniter 2.1 - character replace

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a felling that something is trolling me. I have this two functions. Purpose is to replace characters, but something is not working. Name of the file is changed, but only **space** (" ") is changed to **_** character (there are no more str_replace functions).
What is wrong?

**EDIT**
**char_replace** is found in separate library file which is not extending controller.
I am using **char_replace** function to replace data coming from **input type=text** and it is working (function is being called from different controller).

```
function img_upload($folder) {
        $this->path = './public/img/' . $folder;
        $imgs = array();
        $config = array(
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif',
            'upload_path' => $this->path
        );

        $this->CI->load->library('upload', $config);

        foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {
            $img_name = $this->char_replace($key->name, '_');
            $config['file_name'] = $img_name;
          if($key != 'logo') :
              if (!$this->CI->upload->do_upload($key)) {
            } else {
                $q = $this->CI->upload->data();
                $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image'] = $this->path . '/' . $q['file_name'];
                $config['new_image'] = $this->path . '/thumbs';
                $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                $config['width'] = 128;
                $config['height'] = 128;

                $this->CI->load->library('image_lib');
                $this->CI->image_lib->clear();
                $this->CI->image_lib->initialize($config);
                $this->CI->image_lib->resize();
                array_push($imgs, $q['file_name']);
            }
          endif;
        }

        if(empty($imgs)){
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return implode(',', $imgs);
        }
    }
```

And this one:

```
function char_replace($text, $rep_simbol = " ")
    {
        $char = array('!', '&', '?', '/', '/\/', ':', ';', '#', '<', '>', '=', '^', '@', '~', '`', '[', ']', '{', '}');
        return $name = str_replace($char, $rep_simbol, $text);
    }
```

Comment: Is `$this->char_replace()` calling the right function?

Comment: Both functions are in the same class. I think that is the way to call function which is in the same class.

Comment: `foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {` then `$this->char_replace($key->name, '_');`. Does `$key->name` work ?

Comment: PHP manual says that to reach name of uploaded file you need to go **$_FILES['file']['name']**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {
  $img_name = $this->char_replace($key->name, '_');
  ...
```

Here `$key->name` will be undefined and so `char_replace` will return an empty string. Since `file_name` is empty, Codeigniter Upload library will fallback to its `_prep_filename` method.

Use `$value['name']` instead of `$key->name`.

If you are uploading multiple files with the `file` field having the same name

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($_FILES as $filename => $values) {
  $img_name = is_array($values['name']) ? $values['name'][$count] : $values['name'];
  $img_name = $this->char_replace($img_name, '_');
  $count++;
```

Comment: How can I get name of uploaded file?

Comment: Changing to $value['name'] solved the problem :). Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Sasha sorry, if you are uploading multiple files as you seem to be, that would be wrong. I have updated my answer for that case. Try that.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you, but something strange is happening (I have notice this by accidence). Function is working but it is using only first symbol (it cuts symbols after first) and all images after first have the same name (a counting number is added in order not to overwrite). And if I upload one image it is doing the same thing. What is going on here?

Comment: Edited code. The earlier code would have worked if you were uploading multiple files having the same field names. If uploading a single file or multiple files with different field names it was incorrect.

Comment: Well, everyday you learn something new :). Thank you again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the replacement has to have at least as many elements as the search:

```
function char_replace($text, $rep = " ")
{
    $char = array('!', '&', '?', '/', '/\/', ':', ';', '#', '<', '>', '=', '^', '@', '~', '`', '[', ']', '{', '}');
    $replace = array($rep, $rep, $rep, $rep, %rep, $rep, $rep, $rep, $rep, $rep, $rep, $rep, $rep, $rep, $rep, $rep, $rep, $rep, $rep);
    return $name = str_replace($char, $replace, $text);
}
```

Comment: According to PHP manual the way I wrote the code is good. I forgot to say, char_replace function is used in another function and it is working (it is replacing text from input field type=text).

Comment: @Sasha:  Oh, it looks like [you are right](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).  I did not read beyond the phrase *If **replace** has fewer values than **search**, then an empty string is used for the rest of replacement values.*